# Special cases of equality between two norms

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, matrix-norms

Let $\mathcal{L}(E)$ be the algebra of all bounded linear operators on **an infinite dimensional** complex Hilbert space $E$.
On $\mathcal{L}(E)^2$, we have two equivalent norms:
\begin{eqnarray*}
N_1(A,B)
&=&\sup\left\{\|Ax\|^2+\|Bx\|^2,\;x\in E,\;\|x\|=1\;\right\},
\end{eqnarray*}
and
$$N_2(A,B)=\|A\|^2+\|B\|^2.$$

Clearly, $N_1(A,B)\leq N_2(A,B)$.

> In general $N_1\neq N_2$. I want to find special cases for equality. I claim that: if $AB=BA$ and $A$ et $B$ are normal operators on $E$, then
> $$N_1(A,B)= N_2(A,B).$$
> Is my claim correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt. Consider $E=\mathbb{C}^2$, $A=\rm{diag}(1,0)$ and $B=\rm{diag}(0,1)$.
Then $A$ and $B$ are selfadjoint, hence normal, and $AB=BA=0$. Now
$$
N_1(A,B)=\sup\{\|A{x\choose y}\|^2 +\|B{x\choose y}\|^2: ~ {x\choose y} \in E, ~ |x|^2+|y|^2=1\}=1,
$$
but $N_2(A,B)=\|A\|^2+\|B\|^2=2$.